# How to cache data in a web application?

Tags: javascript, caching, web-applications

I am developing an ExtJS application but the server supplying my data/services tend to go down frequently in a completely out of my hands situation. Is there a way to store the responses from API calls in a web application such that when the services return 404 later on, the web application simply use cached data ? I am using ExtJS 4.2 and FireFox as the web browser. The API calls are GET/POST requests. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: you should post you're try to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can store datas in LocalStorage object, but you must do the request before.

```
localStorage.requestDatas1=response;
```

But if the user choose to delete browser cache you'll loose the localstorage object.

So if you want to do that, you should previously choose to make server work.

If you won't use the localStorage you can use a store with a memory proxy (on page reload lose datas) or a localstorage proxy (same to use localStorage).

If you have an hard structure you should a store, with an associated model, and store your datas whit the localStorage proxy. On request succes you only need to update the store.